# Mongo Cursor Hangs after first fetch

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I am running a lookup query using aggregation pipeline.
While iterating over the cursor returned from aggregation execution, I have noticed  that program hangs when Mongo sends getMore command. I believe this command is used to fetch next batch of records from DB.

Initially I tested with Batch size of 100, it brings 100 records fairly quickly, but when it tries to fetch next set of records, cursor hangs.
I tried the same with batch size of 2 and got the same result.

I am using Mongo Java Driver version 3.6 and server 3.6.2.
I also found that there was a similar issue raised for python driver in the past(https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-276).

Has anyone experienced this in the past ? Any suggestions would be helpful.
Let me know if any other details are required

Comment: Have the same problem

Comment: Did anyone find the solution to this?